# Original Windows 7 Home Premium on Acer Aspire 5740G

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

Is it posible to get the original Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit for the Acer Aspire 5740G? I bought this notebook and the license for this Windows is in the package. There is an partition with the data for the recovery. But than, there are a lot of senseless application which I don't want to use. I'm searchin for the complete clear Windows 7 Home Premium.

I tried to download the original Windows 7 Home Premium and entered the serial key of the bottom of the laptop but I can't activate my Windows with this key.

Any ideas or experiens with this?

Comment: What message do you get when you try to activate?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience from working with crappy proprietary software pre-installed on laptops (all I did at my old job was clean that crap off people's computers) is that it's easier to download an image of a Win7 CD (retail: not illegal; you own a license) and install it on your computer. I have never had a problem using an OEM cd key on a retail disc; they are fundamentally the same. OEM discs and retail discs are the same, just one is supported by the manufacturer.

So, some simplified steps:

1. Download a copy of your version of the Win7 install disc (if your key is for Professional, download Professional etc.)
2. Install that copy of Win7 on your computer overwriting the existing Win7 install (you may delete the recovery partition if you wish, and some do, but I recommend against doing so unless you really need the space; it can come in handy later)
3. Activate Win7 using the CD-key on the bottom of the computer (or in the manual or wherever the Certificate of Authenticity is)

(sometimes Microsoft will tell you to call a centre in your region to activate over the phone; this is normal once the license has already been used. Just repetitively assure the computer that you're only installing it on ONE machine and you'll be fine).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** After reading over more carefully, you want to make sure you're downloading the exact same version of Windows 7 that was installed on your computer. For example, WXPVOL_EN.iso (the disc name for XP Pro) is **different** than VRMPVOL_EN.iso (also for XP pro). This can take a bit of work, but it should activate no matter what. I'll bet if you call the activation centre in your country they'll let you install it. They always did for me.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has an OEM version of Windows 7 Home Premium which has a serial number that is not compatible with the retail versions of Windows 7 Home Premium.
That said, *Windows itself* should not be different between the OEM version and the retail version. You should be able to just uninstall all the Acer stuff. There might even be a system restore point.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got acer aspire 3I 5740g lappie. It wont create the backup disc from Acer Recovery Management I get this error. (Hard Drive Configuration is not set to the factory default. Restore Aborted. It makes the driver recovery disc no problems. This is annoying why wont it backup to disc from the hidden partition to dvd. If I reboot and hold ALT and tap F10 it says missing operating system. I just sent a Gateway nv54 back for the same reason My Daughter has a gateway NV54 and it does the same think. This is crazy support cant fix it. All I want to do is make a restore disc like it says in the event I have to restore the laptop. Whats the point in having the operating system sticker underneath if you cant make a backup.

Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

DigitalRiver [offers](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/boot-disks.html#full) legitimate, legal, downloads of the Windows 7 ISO file.  Download the correct version, 32 or 64 bit and home premium professional etc, and burn the disc and install from that.  However you will have to track down and install your own device drivers - those are typically not included on the generic ISO.  A tip, as I have done this myself, while installing it will ask for your product-key, put it in but do not select automatic activation.  Instead install the disc and then once installed go into the control panel and choose the system applet then choose change product key and put in your same product-key as you did in the installation.  If you don't do it this way then the product-key will fail to activate, however if you do and your product-key is legitimate then it will work.